# How to Upgrade Bluefish Version?

Tags: 11.04, upgrade, bluefish

I have Ubuntu 11.04 natty OS. I have Bluefish 2.0.2 version, I want to upgrade this version to Bluefish 2.2.5 on same OS. I don't want to change or upgrade my OS (ubuntu 11.04). If any one has perfect solution , then please do reply asap.

Comment: Your OS is no longer supported, but yes I have a no OS upgrade solution. Download the source (and dependencies) and build it yourself.

Comment: from where i have to download it.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please, could you put some of your time to read http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to download and install the following packages from trusty (2.2.5-1), choose the ones for your architecture (`amd64` or `i386`):

- http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/bluefish
- http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/bluefish-data
- http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/bluefish-plugins

Install the three deb files that you'll get like this:

```
sudo dpkg -i ./bluefish*.deb
```

Comment: Thanks but these versions are not supporting my system.